# Always animate UIView to user's tap location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, core-animation

I have a UIView that I want to animate to the position where the user's finger currently is.

So, when the touch begins, it has to animate to the tap location.

When the touch moves, it has to adjust its destination to the new location.

When the touch ends, it has to finish the animation to the last tap location.

I tried several things but none worked out. I tried creating a new animation with beginsFromCurrentState in `touchesMoved`, but that didn't work too.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you're complicating this a little bit. If you are implementing touchesMoved, you are wanting a drag. If you are more interested in a tap, then touchesEnded is where you want to implement this. Either way, you just need to get the location in view and update your UIView's center based upon that location. If you wrap the change to the center value in a UIView animation block, it will animate to the position as it updates.

If you are using iOS 3.2 or later, you can use gesture recognizers which makes this pretty trivial:

```
// In viewDidLoad or some such
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                         initWithTarget:self action:@selector(viewWasTapped:)];
[[self view] addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Then declare your action selector:

```
- (void)viewWasTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
  CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:[self view]];
  [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
  [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0f]; // take a second to animate
  [viewToMove setCenter:location];
  [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

This will animate the view from one location to another. This is referred to as implicit animation. Using Core Animation classes such CAKeyframeAnimation or CABasciAnimation would be explicit animation.

Answer (score 0):

Need a few more details for this.. But are you sure you are using `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved` and `touchesEnded` from the appropriate view (ie not the view you want to move)?  Also make sure the `userInteractionEnabled = YES`.  Try logging the touches from `touchesBegan` to make sure you are receiving the touches.

Or you might want to just check out Apples `MoveMe` sample code at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoveMe/Introduction/Intro.html where they have solved all those problems for you.

Comment: The MoveMe sample is not exactly what I want. The MoveMe shows a draggable view. I need a view that just follows the user's location. It's not really the same.

Comment: And yes, the `touchesBegan`, etc. methods get all called, the problem is I don't know how to setup the correct animations so that it results in the behavior I want.

Comment: What's the difference between MoveMe and what you want to do?

Comment: The MoveMe needs to be dragged. Mine doesn't need to be dragged. It just follows, no matter where you tap.